# Why does pos behave different with cycle then with other path segments?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using `pos` to align nodes along a path. This works great, even with special segments like `-|`. But I came across an issue when using `cycle`. It seems for `cycle` `pos` does not work at all. That would be fine for me, but I do not even receive an error. So maybe I am doing something wrong or not looking at it the right way?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -| ++(2,2) -| ++(-2,-2) node[pos=0.5]{O};
    
    \draw (3,0) -| ++(2,2) -| cycle node[pos=0.5]{X};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Judging by the source, the `cycle` will always be converted to `(current subpath start) -- cycle` unless `cycle` directly followed `--`. So closing a path will always end on a straight line segment, even if that's a segment of length zero. I'd always put nodes/coordinates/pic directly after the path operation (here `-|`) unless you have to work with `\tikztonodes` (which isn't allowed after the path operation) but you know now to use `-| (current subpath start) \tikztonodes -- cycle` then instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to solve it

There are two ways of placing a node on a line: [explicitly](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.8), as you did in your code, or [implicitly](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.9), as I do in the following code.
When using the implicit approach, you can omit `pos=0.5`, as it is the default. It is still possible to set any other `pos=x` there.
With the implicit approach, it works as expected.

(*Note:* For horizontal/vertical line-to operations `|-` and `-|` the position `0.5` is exactly the corner point, as you can see with `\draw (3,0) -| ++(2,1) -| node{X} cycle;`)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -| ++(2,2) -| node{O} ++(-2,-2);
    %\draw (3,0) -| ++(2,2) -| node[pos=0.5]{X} cycle;
    \draw (3,0) -| ++(2,2) -| node{X} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

### Approach of the *why*

The problem does not arise when using `-- cycle node[midway]{foo}`. It seems that `cycle` is defined correctly only for the connection `--`. In the [tikz code](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L2941) there is a comment:

```tex
% Syntax for cycle:
% -- cycle
```

So the problem seems to be, that the combination of `pos` and `cycle` is not defined for other connections than `--`.

Comment: Putting the node before cycle also works with [pos=0.75] for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, you can of course set any `[pos=...]` there. I just omitted it from the code, as `[pos=0.5]` is already the default position.

Comment: Thanks @dexteritas it explains how I can achieve what I want, but technically it does not answer my question. ;-)

Comment: @TobiBS I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: `cycle` will be converted to `(current subpath start) -- cycle` unless it followed `--` which will lead to the node to be placed on a straight segment of length 0.